# Change range of ng2-nouislider dynamically

Tags: angular, nouislider, viewchild

I have a loop that creates different ng2-noUiSliders like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let property of completeFilters">
            <h5>{{property.propertyName | translate}}</h5>
            <div *ngIf="setSliderValues(property); else renderCheckbox">
              <nouislider #sliderRef [config]="conf" [tooltips]="[true, true]" (end)="onSliderChange($event, property.propertyName)"></nouislider>
            </div>
```

The sliders created are range sliders and one of them is a price slider. When changing currency I'd like to update the slider min max with other values. So far I'm able to pick up the sliders like this:

```
@ViewChildren('sliderRef') public salesSliders: QueryList<NouisliderComponent>;

this.salesSliders.toArray()[0]; //the slider I want to update
this.salesSliders.toArray()[1];
...
```

But I can't get it to work with updateOptions examples I've seen. Has anybody done this when having more than one slider that is created in a loop like in my case?

Answer (score 0):

To update your UI with latest values you need to do the below steps

```
    // Import this in componnet where your are updating the values
    import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'; 
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}


    //call below method after you changes
    this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Comment: That didn't help. I can see that the conf are getting the updated values but it's not rerendering the slider with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

```
let s1 = this.salesSliders.toArray()[0];
let s2 = this.salesSliders.toArray()[1];

    s1.slider.on('change.one', function (event) {
      let conf = {
        behaviour: 'drag',
        tooltips: true,
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
          min: [5],//any numeric value or value from s1 slider
          max: [25]//any numeric value
        },
        format: {
          to: function ( value ) {
            return value;
          },
          from: function ( value ) {
            return value;
          }
        },
        pips: {
          mode: 'steps',
          stepped: true,
          density: 2
        },
        step: 2,
        start: 5,//any numeric value or value from s1 slider for position of handle
        end: 25//any numeric value
      }
  s2.slider.updateOptions(conf,true); // way to use updateOptions()
})
```

here you need to use "slider" property. I have used slide event. You can check for more event